# Is it possible to execute cgi from flask?

Tags: python, flask, cgi

I am thinking about replacing lighttpd in an embedded project with flask and its embedded server, because I don't need all features of lighttpd, while I'd like to use flask's functionalities.

I have one doubt: I have a CGI program written in C that needs to be executed by the web server. Is it possible to use the embedded server of flask to execute other CGI programs?

Comment: Flask doesn't have an embedded server except for the development one, which as the name implies is strictly for development. You should not try and run it in a production scenario.